# Creating a vm using Hyper-V causes the host of BSOD

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, hp

**Problem description:**
When I try to create a virtual machine, the host bsod part way through the process. From the logs in lookes to fail/hang on the "Creating new VirtualDisckDriver with new VHD" step.

The BSOD error code is SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION : STOP:0x0000003B
When the machine has finished restarting, it looks to have created the vhd and XML files for the vm but it isn't accessable.

I have two server bothing behaving in exactly the same way, so I don't believe it's a hardware fault.

Has anyone had a similar experince? How did you resolve the problem?

**NOTES**
Hardware: HP DL380 G6
BIOS : 2010.03.30 (14 Apr 2010) [Latest from HP website]
      Inter Hyperthreading: Disabled
      Intel Virtuazation Technology : Enabled
      No-Execute Memory Protection: Enabled
Mem check reports no errors
OS: Windows 2008 Sp2 x64bit fully updated
Driver - Storage Controller :6.20.0.64

**Edit: 15:03**
Playing with creating different types of virtual machines. Creating the vm without a hard disk or NIC. Doesn't result in a BSOD.
I then added a IDE disk, the host bsoded 98% of the way through the "Create new virtualDiskDriver with new VHD" step.
I'm leaning towards a driver issue with the Smart Array, I think

regards
Arcass

Comment: Are the two servers the same hardware?  I have this same O/S setup  with many vm's running on it and have no issues.

Comment: Yep both server have the same hardware.

Comment: did you hit the server with the newest smartstart to update all the drivers and most importantly firmware?  This is non R2 correct? Because if it was there are several hotfixes available.

Comment: Ype, used SmartStart 8.40 on both after the OS was installed.

OS is Windows 2008 SP2 x64bit (not R2).

Comment: any antivirus software running on the host?

Comment: no antivirus has been installed in the host yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after too many hour wasted trying to resolve this problem. This morning I took the decision to flatten the server and rebuild using Win 2008 Enterprise x64bit (no SP2).

I've just finished the rebuild, I can now create and start VM without the server BSODing.

So I guess something in SP2 is causing the problem. Lession learned, double and triple check supportablitiy before rushing off and using the most up-to-date version of an OS.

Answer (score 0):

> it looks to have created the vhd and
>   XML files for the vm but it isn't
>   accessable.

Seems like its a permission issue from this line above..

ADDITION

I have the same server. Make sure your hardware is up to date with the latest firmwares. There are some known random reboot issues. Though not the same as your issue old firmware revisions could cause issues like this. Let us know if you are up to date.

Comment: permission issue shouldn't blue screen

Comment: I completely agree. I have the same server. Make sure your hardware is up to date with the latest firmwares. There are some known random reboot issues. Though not the same as your issue old firmware revisions could cause issues like this. Let us know if you are up to date.
I added this to my answer.